# Number of developer and Sandbox edition in use

Tags: administration, sandbox, sandbox-refresh, developer-org, unlimited

I have a unlimited production license. I am not sure how many developer org and sandbox box are associated with my production org. How can I get to know these numbers?

Comment: There are Developer Edition orgs and various types of sandboxes - full, developer, developer pro, etc.. Ratan states how to find the sandboxes. Whether they are in use or not requires logging into each one and looking at other things like View Setup Audit Trail or login history

Comment: How many sandbox and developer edition is available for an unlimited lisence? Thanks

Comment: 1 Full  , 
5 Dev. Pro ,
15 Developer you can create. check this doc http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/ap/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

goto setup --> left quick search --> type sandbox--> click on link

you can see all the associated sandbox list

FOR unlimited licence

you can create

1 Full  ,

5 Dev. Pro ,

15 Developer

check this doc http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/ap/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf